# How to access to nested view using data binding and navigation component?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-jetpack

I'm using android data binding and navigation component. I have `activity_member` layout. This layout includes another layout:

```
    <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/appbar" />
```

and in `app_bar_main` layout include another layout:

```
        <include
        android:id="@+id/member"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

In `content_main`I want to put main host fragmnet for using navigation component:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".ui.MembersPage.MemberActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-29dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="215dp"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is the host fragment in navigation graph. I need to access recyclerView in java class but I can not:

```
        binding.appbar.member.membersRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
```

and:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MembersFragment"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/membersRecycler"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

How to access to nested elements in this situation like recyclerView id here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should put the RecyclerView tag in the fragment layout and use DataBinding in the fragment class.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example of how you can access views in your situation.

Let's say you have a String `title` inside class object `myObject` to pass from `activity_member` to `app_bar_main` and your object is defined like this in `activity_member`.

```
 <data>
    <variable
      name="myObject"
      type="com.example.model.Object"/>
  </data>
```

Now to pass string named `title` which is inside your `myObject` to `app_bar_main`, you will have to define the variable in `app_bar_main`
 like this

```
 <data>
    <variable
      name="title"
      type="String"/>
  </data>
```

after doing so, you will be able to pass the title from where you had included `app_bar_main` in `activity_member` layout.

```
 <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/appbar" 
    app:title = "@{myObject.title}"/>
```

Also, now you will be able to access all views which are inside `app_bar_main`. Let's say you have a view with id `myTextView`

```
TextView textView = binding.appbar.myTextView;
```